# How to run a single class in Java / using Junit

Tags: java, junit

I'm currently developing a program which as I work gets more and more expansive. Each time I want to test a new `Class` that I've built I have to add and remove methods from my `Main` class to do so. As the program grows this becomes more and more cumbersome.

I've been wanting to write `JUnit` tests for the new classes that I build as I go to check the desired methods. Any tutorial I've looked at describes how to write basic test methods to Assert that a method returns an expected math result or boolean and so on, but that's not what I'm looking to check. I've looked for a while and read quite a bit but I cannot find anything to detail how you would write custom test methods like what I'm looking for.

Consider the class below:

In the case of the `loadFromFile()` method, the expected result would be that it has successfully loaded a text file and parsed it into a `Map<String, String>`, but I'm unable to figure out how to do this.

The current expected result of my `checkDuplicates()` method when finished fully will be to cross check one list of data which gets passed to the constructor on object creation, against another and remove data from one of the lists. I've not finished this method completely, as I want to make sure that in each stage that I write its working properly as I go.

How would I write this sort of method?

```
package com.airport.twitter;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileHandler {
    private Map<String, String> arrivalsMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> departuresMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arrivals = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> departures = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String arrLocation, depLocation;

    public FileHandler(ArrayList<String> arrivals, ArrayList<String> departures) {
        this.arrivals = arrivals;
        this.departures = departures;
        this.arrLocation = "src/main/resources/arrivals.txt";
        this.depLocation = "src/main/resources/departures.txt";
    }

    public Map<String, String> loadFromFile(Map<String, String> list,
            String location) throws IOException {
        String str = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location));
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = str.split("=");
            list.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        br.close();
        return list;
    }

    public void checkDuplicateFlights() throws IOException {
        arrivalsMap = loadFromFile(arrivalsMap, arrLocation);
        ConsolePrinter.printMap(arrivalsMap);
        System.out.println("\n");
        departuresMap = loadFromFile(departuresMap, depLocation);
        ConsolePrinter.printMap(departuresMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you check the result the same as a math result or a boolean? Just use assertEquals instead of assert.

Comment: Perhaps its my lack of understanding of Junit, but I don't need to check that the contents of a Map in the method needs to be equal to say 50 lines of text. I need to check that I have connected successfully to the file, and loaded it into the class correctly if that makes sense. I'd be hoping to view the contents with a print method or something. Are you suggesting something like assertNotNull()?

Comment: Your loadFromFile will throw an IOException if the file is not found. Your programm does what it is supposed to do when the result is as expected: ie. the returned map is correct if the file is found and an IOException is thrown when the file is not found (you'll need at least 2 UnitTests for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your loadFromFile, I would take a File with some values in it an check the result. Since you know the content of the file, you know what the method must return and can test it.

For instance, if the file contains:

```
x=1
y=2
z=3
```

I would run this method in a JUnit-Test class like this:

```
@Test
public void testLoadFromFile()
{
  //...init
  FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
  result = fh.loadFromFile(known_path_to_File);
  assertEquals(expectedMap, result);
  // **here you can be sure that the file was read correctly!**
}
```

assertMap would compare the 2 maps.
expectedMap would contain x=1, y=2 and z=3 and could be initialized like this:

```
private static final Map<String, String> expectedMap;
static {
    Map<String, String> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    aMap.put("x", "1");
    aMap.put("y", "2");
    aMap.put("z", "3");
    expectedMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(aMap);
}
```

By the way:

```
void org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)
```

So you'll need to import like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

The second test you'll have to run (a failure if the file is not found):

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)
public void testFileNotFound()
{
  FileHandler fh = ...//same as previous
  fh = loadFromFile("no real file here.txt");
}
```